# How to connect PHP application to Oracle DB on Red Hat 7.9?

Tags: oracle-linux

My PHP project uses Oracle DB and it runs on Linux environment.

I believe I need to download OCI8 for Linux but I can't find this version of oci8 (`php-oci8-5.4.16-48.el7.rpm`) anywhere.

Can anyone have any clue to solve this issue? Any link/document?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php) on PHP web site you should use `pecl`.

Run this command:

```
pecl install oci8
```

Edit your `php.ini` file and add the line:

```
extension=oci8.so
```

In case of problem follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504052/2908599):

For anyone stumbling upon this question, here is the proper way to handle it in Linux. (I am using CentOS commands for the demo below but Ubnutu shouldn't be any different)

**Step 1**: Get the Oracle libs.

**EDIT**: Thanks to Christopher Jones for the comment, you can find the direct RPM links at `https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/oracle/instantclient/x86_64/`

```
wget oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
wget oracle-instantclient18.3-devel-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**Step 2**: Install.

```
yum install oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install  oracle-instantclient18.3-devel-18.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

**Step 3**: configure (make the path of the oracle libs to be discoverable)

```
sudo sh -c "echo /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: I did all this but no luck :( . I am getting error like No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/oci8". Now how to solve this error?

Comment: Will edit my answer